# Issue with Jenkins Plugin

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

ERROR: [kubernetes-cli] unsupported credentials type com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.credentials.KubeconfigCredentials

The above error is what i get after running this code in jenkins build pipeline

```
   withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'cluster01',
                                        caCertificate:'LS0tLS1CRUdl*******gQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=',
                                        serverUrl: 'https://5B02E040C2*****90118D8BD4.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com',
                                        contextName: 'eks-new-***-01',
                                        clusterName: 'eks-new-***-01',
                                        namespace: 'default'
                                        ]) {
                          sh 'kubectl get pods'
                        }
```

Comment: don't expose sensitive informations in question

Comment: please share the logs in jenkins as well

Comment: Did you upload the file as FileCredential type in Jenkins?

Comment: I have used direct option.

Comment: The corresponding credentials plugin is installed?

Comment: @FaisalBasha Not sure what you mean by "direct option". Have a look at the supported types of credentials: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cli-plugin/blob/master/README.md#supported-credentials If you have installed also this plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin you'll find a misleading credential type, "KubeConfig", which is not compatible with the kubernetes-cli one.

Comment: I have completed it just had to remove caCertificate, contextName, clusternmae & Namespace as they were not needed. It Worked!